# EnumDropDownList MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, scaffolding

I have class

```
public partial class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Shifts Shift { get; set; }
}

public enum Shifts : int
{
    First = 1,
    Second = 2
}
```

and a MVC view code

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Shift, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Shift, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Shift, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

and a controller post code...

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Shift")] Team team)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TeamSet.Add(team);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(team);
    }
```

In my DB, Shift is int type and I'm trying to get values from Enum, but in post from form I get text ("First" or "Second"). I tried to find some documentation EnumDropDownListFor but without success, so if someone have any idea I'll be thankful..

Comment: Documentation can be found here https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/MVC/EnumSample/ReadMe.txt and here http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Enum

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Shifts : int
{

[Display(Name = "First")]
First = 1,

[Display(Name = "Second")]
Second = 2
}
```